# From quotation to sales order by Paypal in ODOO 12

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-12

At the moment when someone buy something in the eCommerce website in ODOO and choose payment by pay-pal, the quotation goes to the sales order automatically. The sale order gets confirmed. Is it possible to do that quotation will stay as an quotation and i would have to accepted order manually?

Answer (score 0):

Just go to sale module and search for **_reconcile_after_transaction_done** method.
There you can find the call of order confirmation line. Simply remove and process.